# Why does faucet work one day and not the next?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, hot-water

This American Standard faucet worked yesterday. But today, water barely trickles from it.
I can rotate it just fine and when I rotate it shut, the trickle stops. My gut feeling is that it catches in one rotation direction but not the other. Water from the adjacent sink flows fine.

**Questions**

1. Why would what seems to be a perfectly good faucet no longer work?
2. I've removed the bolt from the center but nothing comes loose. How do I disassemble it?
3. Any suggestion on how to get water flowing again?

[image: AmericanStandardFaucet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) The knobs should pull off. They may be glued in place by mineral accumulation over the years; try wiggling them to break that free.

1, 3) Depends on the type of valve; several are in common use. You won't know what you've got until you have it open.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot remove the valve and you suspect debris, then remove any fixtures aerators adjacent to it and then figure out a way to pressurize the fixture you deem blocked...blow that stuff right out. Will it cause more damage than good? Likely, but we all had fun now, didn't we?